# How do you obtain covariance from manufacturer datasheet?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking through the imu driver code ([microstrain_3dmgx2_imu](http://www.ros.org/wiki/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu)) to understand how I can write a driver for my own IMU.

I notice the parameters for orientation/angular velocity/linear acceleration stdev were derived from the manufacturer datasheet ("The default value, derived from the manufacturer datasheet, is very conservative.")

What I would like to know is, how is this derivation done? For example, if the "Accelerometer nonlinearity" is 0.2%, and "Accelerometer bias stability" 0.010 g, how do I get the variance?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12413/how-do-you-obtain-covariance-from-manufacturer-datasheet?/) by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2268 on 2011-12-20

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2012-01-09**:
Related: http://answers.ros.org/question/413/how-do-i-compute-the-covariance-matrix-for-an

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out that the "Accelerometer bias stability" is the standard deviation. So variance is just the square of it -- in this case (0.010 g)^2

note: g is the gravitational accel 9.81ms^-2

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2